# How to disable only the checkboxes (and not the full checkedboxlist) of devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In non-edit mode, I need the user to be able to browse the list (scroll etc.) but not be able to select the checkboxes.

If I do `checkedboxlist.enabled = false`, then the whole list becomes disabled. Only I need to disable checkboxes so that user doesn't interact (in edit way) in non-edit mode.

**EDIT**
I just assign the list of strings to the checkedboxlist's datasource.

```
        this.UserSelectedMsgTypes.DataSource = userSelectedMsgs;
        this.UserAvailableMsgTypes.DataSource = availableMsgTypeList;
```

currently enabling/disabling whole list by doing

```
        this.UserSelectedMsgTypes.Enabled = true/false;
        this.UserAvailableMsgTypes.Enabled = true/false;
```

I tried @James solution earlier, doesnt work. Because somehow the 'ItemCount' is 0 even though there are items. in the datasource it shows that there are 6 items, but in list it shows 0.

Comment: Does it have IsEditable (or Editable) property? Usually this prop should be the way to go.

Comment: what code does your .aspx page currently have, please share the small section.

Comment: its winforms code. pls see EDIT in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    foreach (DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem item in checkedListBoxControl1.Items)
    {
        item.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, doesnt work. Because somehow the 'ItemCount' is 0 even though there are items. in the datasource it shows that there are 6 items, but in list it shows 0.

Comment: What does you datasource look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a dirty work around but how about this?

```
private IEnumerable<DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem> GetCheckItems(string[] myStringArray)
{
    foreach(string s in myStringArray)
    {
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem item = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem();
        item.Description = s;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Call with:

```
checkedListBoxControl1.Items.AddRange(GetCheckItems(new string[] {"test1","test2","test3"}).ToArray());
```

Then apply the first answer with the foreach loop (or set the ENabled = false in the GetCheckItems method).

Comment: I think there is a bug in the dev express control because as you said a datasource setting produces zero items in the list which is obviously not quite right.